# A simple message box with please wait message.without buttons?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to Create A simple message box with please wait message.without buttons? please tell me how can i do that.

Comment: The "built-in" message box cannot do this, but you can easily create your own dialog for this.

Comment: If i can create a dialogue box why should i ask this .I have done research through google about this .I didn't find answer to this any one having another i have posted here to there is any other solution than message box and dialogue box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CString strFinalData(_T("Please wait.Print Spooler Service restart may take several minutes.."));
DialogTemplate dialogTemplate(_T("Please wait"), WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU,10, 10, 250, 30);
dialogTemplate.AddStatic(_T(""),WS_VISIBLE | ES_READONLY, 0,10, 10, 250, 30, 15899);
pWaitDialogue = new CDialog();
pWaitDialogue->CreateIndirect(dialogTemplate);
pWaitDialogue->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
CWnd *pWnd = pWaitDialogue->GetDlgItem(15899);
pWnd->SetWindowText(strFinalData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [XMessageBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox). You don't say how the message box will eventually get removed (?), so without further information I think you can achieve what you want by making use of it's timer.

> Countdown timer for default button - setting the nTimeoutSeconds member to a positive value will cause XMessageBox() to display a countdown timer on the default button. When the timeout expires, the default button id (OR'd with MB_TIMEOUT) will be returned as if the user had pressed the button.